# mysql как не перечислять все поля если нужно 1 поле изменить при SELECT

Tags: mysql

Хай. Подскажите можно ли не перечислять все поля если 1 поле из 20 нужно немного изменить при запросе:

```
SELECT *, SEC_TO_TIME(duration_seconds) as duration_seconds FROM videos;
```

В этом случае получается 2 поля duration_seconds 1-ое с int, 2-e c time:

```
id | name | ... |  duration_seconds | duration_seconds
 1 | test | ... |         30        |      00:00:30
```

Как получить только 1 поле с time не перечисляя все поля в Select?
 Что бы не писать запрос такого рода:

```
SELECT bla, bla, bla, bla, SEC_TO_TIME(duration_seconds), bla, bla, .... FROM ...
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Сформулируйте его иначе.

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Изменил! Только не говорите, что и сейчас не понятен!

Comment: Никак. Перечисляйте. Дело простое, и рук не оборвёт.

Comment: @Akina ну это если 1 запрос, то можно, а если их много разных, то это напрягает...

Comment: *а если их много разных* то для каждого это надо сделать всего один раз. Точнее, для каждой таблицы, потенциально могущей быть источником данных такого запроса, один раз получить список всех полей - да и это можно сделать не руками, а запросом из information_schema.columns.

Comment: @Akina вообщем понятно... лучше уже конвертну циклом на уровне языка, нежели писать лишние запросы...

Comment: "Чем выучить, как правильно, и потом сделать правильно, лучше сделаю через опу - по крайней мере это-то я умею, да так и быстрее будет..." Ну и такая точка зрения имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @Akina я вот только не пойму зачем делать из себя всю такую правильную и да еще дерзить? Ты типо не выводишь ничего циклом и не корректируешь? Даже на уровне шаблона когда циклом что-то отображаешь выводишь все как есть? И поле Date не форматируешь, на что-то похожее на дд.мм.гггг? Да лучше я напишу простую фунцию для шаблона "ConvertIntToTime" зато это быстрей сделать, понятней, не нарушает структуру и работает быстро, нежели буду опу твою юзать. Или это через опу? Да? Или что, ты моя ясная, подразумеваешь через "Чем выучить, как правильно, и потом сделать правильно, лучше сделаю через опу"?

Comment: Так если не нужны другие поля, может убрать `*` из запроса?

Comment: @NikitaUmnov ты вообще читал вопрос или ты такой умный что твое IQ не понимаю?

Comment: *Ты типо не выводишь ничего циклом и не корректируешь? Даже на уровне шаблона когда циклом что-то отображаешь выводишь все как есть?* Во-первых, я храню данные в правильном формате - во всяком случае, мне в голову не придёт интервал времени хранить как целое. Во-вторых, если хочется шаблонизации, то про запросы вообще следует забыть и вынести всю логику на сервер в формат хранимых процедур. А там уже пользуй UDF, на какие фантазии хватит.

Comment: *Или что, ты моя ясная, подразумеваешь через "Чем выучить, как правильно, и потом сделать правильно, лучше сделаю через опу"?* Твой ответ ясно и однозначно говорит "MySQL для меня тёмный лес, поэтому я всё буду делать на клиенте". Это и есть "через опу" - каждая работа должна выполняться тем инструментом, который для неё предназначен, а не тем, который оказался под рукой и более-менее подходит. И - прежде чем делать необоснованные предположения, можно было в профиль заглянуть.

Comment: @bsbak ты за помощью сюда пришёл или слюной плевать? Мысли формулировать научись, может не придётся орать тогда на окружающих

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой несложный запрос:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',\n')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
  AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

вернёт список полей таблицы. Останется только скопипастить...

Comment: этого не достаточно, еще нужно как минимум заменить подстроку в этой строке, потом, что бы это не делать постоянно, нужно кешировать готовый фрагмент запроса, и потом получается, что разные куски кода разбросаны через опу по всему приложению.

Comment: @bsbak *этого не достаточно, еще нужно как минимум заменить подстроку в этой строке* Этого ДОСТАТОЧНО, чтобы ОДИН РАЗ написать запрос. Или представление. А надеяться, что нужная конвертация сама собой появится - напрасное занятие. *и потом получается, что разные куски кода разбросаны через опу по всему приложению* Можно подумать, кто-то тебя заставляет хардкодить запросы...

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли не перечислять все поля если 1 поле из 20 нужно немного изменить при запросе:

```sql
    SELECT *, SEC_TO_TIME(duration_seconds) as duration_seconds FROM videos;
```

Если нужны ВСЕ поля плюс 1 измененное - то Ваш запрос вполне себе нормальный. Только слегка поменять имя вычисляемого поля - и можно не париться.

```sql
    SELECT *, SEC_TO_TIME(duration_seconds) as duration_time FROM videos;
```

Теперь у Вас есть все поля плюс 1 - в дополнительном формате. Имена не дублируются и показывают смысл поля. Лишние пару килобайт при выборке не повлияют существенно на скорость обработки, обработка в коде PHP займет не меньше времени. Тем более, никогда заранее не знаешь, понадобиться ли длительность непосредственно в секундах. Глядишь, понадобиться - а она уже есть. :)

P.S. Мне приходилось видеть в продакшн-коде даже такие конструкции:

```php
    function GetUserPaysData($userid){
    $script="SELECT * from `pays` WHERE `userid`=".$userid." and `txn_id`<>'' ORDER BY `added` DESC";
    $data=DBaseQuery($script);
    $result=DBaseFetchByColumnToArray($data,'id');
    return $result;
    }
```

Т.е. ради одного столбца (первичного ключа, кстати) брали всю запись. И ничё, работает! Правда я в тот код влазить боюсь, там чуть тронь - и всё развалится... :)